# RegEx: Including an attribute check in the same element

Tags: c#, .net, regex

**The end aim**... to retrieve a group of DIVs with specific attributes/values and update the element type and manipulate the attribute and value...

I'd like to use RegEx to test the following **scenario** (I believe is correct based on the above aim)

- for each opening DIV
- that contains an `attribute-to-check` attribute

  - The attribute may or may *not* be the first attribute
- that has a value containing `value-contains`

  - The value may or may *not* be the first value in the attribute (allowing for future extensions)
- find **its** closing DIV

  - This DIV itself may contain other DIVs - **including** other DIVs that will also be matched

So what have I **tried**? ...Using the test script:

```
<p>test1</p>
<DIV attribute-to-check='notvalid'>
  test2
</DIV>
<p>test3</p>
<DIV attribute-to-check='value-contains:2012-12-12' class='test4'>
  test5
</DIV>
<p>test6</p>
<DIV attribute-to-check='value-contains:2012-01-01' class='asd'>
  test6
</DIV>
<p>test7</p>
```

I've got as far as the following RegEx...

```
<?DIV.*?attribute-to-check='value-contains:.*?>(.*?)</DIV>
```

BUT this brings back

```
string 1: "<DIV attribute-to-check='notvalid'>test2</DIV>test3<DIV attribute-to-check='value-contains:2012-12-12' class='test4'>test5</DIV>"

string 2: "<DIV attribute-to-check='value-contains:2012-01-01' class='asd'>test6</DIV>"
```

I suspect it's bringing back `test2` in string1 as this has an opening div with the attribute-to-check *but* the value is notvalid? so I'm wondering if I'm getting the first DIV then any number of characters until it locates *any* other `attribute-to-check='value-contains:` and then the closing DIV after that?

I am struggling to navigate from this point and would appreciate any helpers from the community :)

Thanks
Dylan

Comment: This could be done fairly simply in jquery. Is that available to you or are you parsing the html outside of the browser?

Comment: Who is generating these tags? If its you then regex isn't suitable.

Comment: Avoid lazy quantifiers, they're terribly slow. Rethink your regex completely. Anyway, what's the *first value* in the attribute? Is the attribute value some sort of list? What's its format?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/684934

Comment: Needs to be done server side - C#.   I don't generate the end-HTML and have no control over it.   the attribute value is currently ONLY as shown above - however I want to consider it COULD contain other values going forward (if that over-complicates it I can caveat that out)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, [Don't use regex for HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). [No](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/11/parsing-html-the-cthulhu-way.html), [seriously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not), [don't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701166/can-you-provide-some-examples-of-why-it-is-hard-to-parse-xml-and-html-with-a-reg).

JQuery has awesome selector syntax to do just what you want, really. Look [here](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/), where it shows you how to do what you want way at the top of the documentation.

For example:

```
$('div[attribute-to-check|="value-contains:"]')
```

Will yield divs with your required attribute/value constraint.

Comment: Tim - thanks for the response... I've used the JQuery library before and agree that it's very useful - but the end result is for me to perform this update within .Net (I had tagged this incorrectly with JavaScript). I can't parse this as HTML (or XHTML or XML) as the end "string" is not controlled by me and cannot be guaranteed to to be valid in terms of formatting.

Comment: Hi Dylan, can you not use a parsing library like http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ for example?

Comment: Hi Tim, with no access to  deployed environment Im stuck with .Net & end page HTML (pre-my processing)... As I have no control over the end page. I've issues with the complexity that could exist in the HTML and the DIVs I need to change anyway ... I am considering an approach of retrieving the DIVs that I am concerned with and then if I wrap them in a container test if they are valid XML - if they are - I can update the necessary node(s), remove the wrapper and replace into the RegEx Match... if they are not I would have to depend on string manipulation with the defence these should be valid

Comment: Did you look at the HTML Agility Pack I linked? It's a library for .NET.

Comment: Indeed Tim. Looks great but I can't deploy anything to the existing environment.

Comment: Ah, sorry about that. Good luck with your impossible task then :)

Comment: Indeed - thanks Tim. This will clearly be a nightmare (if even possible) when the div I require is in or contains nested <div>. So I need to either agree that (unlikely) or agree getting to the content in a parseable format before it's pushed onto a HTML page where the format may not be parseable. Thanks for your comments all the same.